# Why does « action » mean (corporate) shares, when English "action" doesn't?

Tags: étymologie, finance

To unburden me from punctuation marks, I highlight in gray `action` to  refer to the English noun. ***action*** in bold italics refers to the French feminine noun.

`action` share some meanings with ***action***. One similarity is  act or deed. Another is  lawsuit.

But in (conversational) English, `action` DOESN'T  mean "shares". So how can ***action*** relate to shares at all? How can ***action*** mean shares, when "action" DOESN'T?

#### I quote Etymonline on [action (n.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/action#etymonline_v_5076) :

> mid-14c., accioun, "cause or grounds for a lawsuit,"
> from Anglo-French *accioun*, Old French *accion*, *action* (12c.) "action; lawsuit, case,"
> from Latin *actionem* (nominative *actio*) "a putting in motion; a performing, a doing; public acts, official conduct; lawsuit, legal action" (source also of Spanish *accion*, Italian *azione*), noun of action from past-participle stem of *agere* "to do"
> (from PIE root [*ag-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*ag-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "to drive, draw out or forth, move").

### Definitions of ***action***, and corporate shares.

> 5. [FINANCE share](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/action/919)
>    [6.  (BUSINESS) (= part dans une société) share](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/action)

[Le Petit Dico En Ligne](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/action)

> 1. Titre cessible et négociable représentant une fraction du capital social de certaines sociétés (➙ [actionnaire](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/actionnaire)). *Actions et obligations. Cote des actions en Bourse.*

["A share is a single unit of ownership in a company or financial asset."](https://marketbusinessnews.com/financial-glossary/share/)
["A “share” indicates a portion of ownership in a particular company. Stocks are divided into shares: a share is the smallest denomination of a company’s stock."](https://www.thestreet.com/investing/stocks-vs-shares)

Comment: "But in (conversational) English, action DOESN'T mean "shares". So how can action relate to shares at all? How can action mean shares, when "action" DOESN'T?" Because English and French are not the same language., There are tons of examples like these between the two languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many words in English come from French but once these [loanwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) get integrated into the language they won't necessarily share the same evolution as their original counterparts. Furthermore specialized lexicon may be grounded in different traditions. In English the word *share* is attested in 1600 ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=share)). In French using *action* to mean "share" is attested since 1665 (DHLF); it seemingly expands on the semantics of the *lawsuit* (*action*) but its evolution is somewhat unclear:

> [...]III. probablement par évolution sémantique à partir de II, terme
> de droit, dans le contexte suivant : dans une association, un associé
> muni d'une *police* ou *billet*, constituant une preuve de son droit
> sur le patrimoine commun, est capable d'intenter une *action* en justice
> sur les fonds de l'association; le terme action a été finalement
> retenu de préférence à billet ou police (d'après. Romeuf t. 1 1956, 19
> b). − L'hypothèse d'un emprunt de sens au néerlandais *Aktie*, terme
> de finance, très vraisemblable du point de vue historique, fait
> difficulté sur le plan chronologique, ce néerlandais n'étant pas
> attesté comme terme de finance avant 1733 (Valkh. 1931, p. 42). −
> L'hypothèse d'une évolution sémantique de action sous l'influence de
> *actif** substantif, finance, fait de même difficulté sur le plan chronologique, *actif* substantif n'étant attesté en ce sens qu'en
> 1762.
>
> [ *Trésor informatisé de la langue française* (TLFi), [*action*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/action/1) ]

The word *action* in French has evolved in a way it seemingly has not in English. Arguably from the analogy with private law and the rights of partners having a promissory note from the firm to leverage litigation against the partnership and claim against its pooled assets. So this meaning of *action* is seemingly based on what remedy the share provided rather than what the *share* stands for (part of the capital).